# Deactivate/removing an iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I have more than 15 thumbnail images displayed(fetched from DB and looped) on the webpage. Onclick of an image, I have an overlay which plays the youtube video(iframe version).

The problem is that, on closing the overlay, the youtube video continues to play.

After going through the YT documentation, I figured out that there is no way to control the YTplayer inside an iframe. But, I have to use an `iframe` because `embed` and `object` tags make use of flash and flash is not supported in Mac(Mountain Lion)

So, I was thinking, if there is a way to deactivate `iframe` then the player may stop. `display:none;` does not help.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript's `removeChild`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method and it works:
I fetch the iframe source by id using javascript and make the source blank.

```
    <script>
    function stopVideo(){

       document.getElementById("iframeID").src= "";

    }
    </script>
```